# anchor target blank - how to always open in same popup window

Tags: asp.net, html

I have a number of anchors in a page. I want that when the user clicks on an anchor it would open a blank window. I have used target='_blank' and that works correctly. However, I want that if the user clicks on another link in the original page, I would like that it uses the same popup that was opened for the first window. What I do not want is that the user ends up with like 10 popups as this would be a bit messy for the user. 

Is this achievable please?

Any assistance would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`target` is deprecated since HTML 4.01, you can however use JS like this:

```
<a href="http://example.com" id="clicky">test</a>
<script>
var clicky = document.getElementById("clicky");

clicky.onclick = function(){
    window.open(clicky.href, "test");    
    return false;        
}​
</script>
```

in the `window.open`, the first attribute is the URL the link should go to, the second is the name of the window, clicking any link setup like this will open in the same window.

there's better and easier ways to do this to multiple elements with jquery etc. but it all hinges on the `window.open`.

Comment: thanks for your very much for this. I did not know that it was depricated. I will use the window open approach and attach it using jquery as you are correctly specifying here

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using [`_blank`](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/linking/_A_TARGET_95y98y108y97y110y107y.html) (which is a special value for a *new* window), use a name - any name would do.

```
target="mySpecialPopup"
```

When naming a window this way, every time you call it by name it uses the same instance.

Answer (score 0):

Just name your target.

```
target='mywindow'
```

This should open a blank window the first click and repopulate it when other target='mywindow' links are clicked.